# How am I able to create an overlay SCNScene on an SKScene in Swift using SpriteKit AR?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I already have a SpriteKit AR game and now I would like to add a SceneKit scene overlay on the SpriteKit scene. I have already created a plane detection code, that uses a SceneKit Node and replaces the plane with an image. I know that there is a function called "scene.overlaySKScene" but how am I able to do the opposite and overlay an SCNScene over an SKScene?

```
  guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelOne") else { return }

        for node in scene.children {
            if let type = createAnchor(in: scene, with: frame, at: node),
                type == .boss {

                createAntiBossWeapon(in: frame)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SK3DNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sk3dnode).

`SKView` doesn't offer an overlay `SCNScene` analogous to `SCNSceneRenderer`'s `overlaySKScene`. But you can place any number of SpriteKit nodes that render SceneKit content in your SpriteKit node hierarchy by using `SK3DNode`.